# Sum values of specific column in multiple files, considering ranges defined in another file

Tags: bash, sum, range, tabular

I have a file (let say file B) like this:

File B:

```
A1  3  5  
A1  7  9  
A2  2  5  
A3  1  3
```

The first column defines a filename and the other two define a range in that specific file. In the same directory, I have also three more files (File A1, A2 and A3).  Here is 10 sample lines from each file:

File A1:

```
1   0.6  
2   0.04 
3   0.4  
4   0.5  
5   0.009
6   0.2  
7   0.3  
8   0.2  
9   0.15 
10  0.1
```

File A2:

```
1  0.2  
2  0.1
3  0.2
4  0.4
5  0.2
6  0.3
7  0.8
8  0.1
9  0.9
10 0.4
```

File A3:

```
1  0.1
2  0.2
3  0.5
4  0.3
5  0.7
6  0.3
7  0.3
8  0.2
9  0.8
10 0.1
```

I need to add a new column to file B, which in each line gives the sum of values of column two in the defined range and file. For example, file B row 1 means that calculate the sum of values of line 3 to 5 in column two of file A1.
The desired output is something like this:

File B:

```
A1  3  5  0.909    
A1  7  9  0.65  
A2  2  5  0.9  
A3  1  3  0.8
```

All files are in tabular text format. How can I perform this task? I have access to bash (ubuntu 14.04) and R but not an expert bash or R  programmer. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: I have updated your question. Please let me know if the formatting is incorrect and also if you have tried my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Given the first file `fileB` and 3 input files `A1`, `A2` and `A3`, each with two columns, this produces the output that you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r file start end; do
    sum=$(awk -vs="$start" -ve="$end" 'NR==s,NR==e{sum+=$2}END{print sum}' "$file")
    echo "$file $start $end $sum"
done < fileB
```

This uses awk to sum up the values between lines between the range specified by the variables `s` and `e`. It's not particularly efficient, as it loops through `$file` once per line of `fileB` but depending on the size of your inputs, that may not be a problem.

Output:

```
A1 3 5 0.909
A1 7 9 0.65
A2 2 5 0.9
A3 1 3 0.8
```

To redirect the output to a file, just add `> output_file` to the end of the loop. To overwrite the original file, you will need to first write to a temporary file, then overwrite the original file (e.g. `> tmp && mv tmp fileB`).